# función pd.rolling_corr

Tags: pandas

Trabajando con una versión 0.23.0 de pandas, intento intento aplicar esta función para ver la correlación de los reornos de dos valores. El código del script es:

```
    import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

start = "2005-1-4"
end = date.today()

# Obtener datos históricos desde Yahoo Finances
tickers = ["IBE.MC", "R4.MC", "TEF.MC", "^IBEX", "^GSPC",
                "^IXIC", "^N225", "^STOXX50E","^DJI"  ]
def get(tickers, start, end):
    def data(ticker):
        return web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    datas = map(data, tickers)
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker','Date']) 
all_data = get(tickers, start, end)

# preparación de los datos.
precio_cierre_ajus  = all_data[['Adj Close']].reset_index()
precio_cierre_ajus_pt = precio_cierre_ajus.pivot_table(values = "Adj Close", index = "Date", columns = "Ticker")
precio_cierre_ajus_pt[:3]

# Variación diaria. Usando la función pct_change
pct_var_diaria = precio_cierre_ajus_pt.pct_change()
# Retorno acumulado
var_diaria_acum = (1 + pct_var_diaria).cumprod()

# Rolling correlation of returns
#rolling_corr = pd.rolling_corr(pct_var_diaria["IBE.MC"], pct_var_diaria["^IBEX"], window=252).dropna()

rolling_corr = pct_var_diaria["IBE.MC"].rolling(252).pct_var_diaria['^IBEX']

rolling_corr[251:] #primeras 251 son NaN
```

Con una opción de la variable rolling_corr, obtengo el error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_corr'
```

Con la otra

```
AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'pct_var_diaria'
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta solución

```
rolling_corr = pct_var_diaria["IBE.MC"].rolling(252).corr(pct_var_diaria['^IBEX'])
```

en:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937271/attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-rolling-corr-while-finding-ro][1]